# Blackberry scoll only browserfield, not entire app-layout

Tags: blackberry, vertical-scrolling, browserfield

I have a verticalfieldmanager with buttons and below that a browserfield. The problem is that when I scroll vertically in the browserfield the whole layout of the app scrolls with it(!).. I've been looking like a mad man for a sollution but haven't found anything yet. I tried disabling vertical scroll in the app but this only results in not being able to scroll the browserfield/homepage.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code helps you: try this;

```
public class NewsBrowserScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{   
String url="http://www.google.com/news/";
VerticalFieldManager vertical;  
BrowserField browserField;
ButtonField click;

public NewsBrowserScreen() 
{           
    createGUI();
}
private void createGUI()    
{   
    click=new ButtonField("Click",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    click.setChangeListener(this);      
    add(click);

    vertical=new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR)
    {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
        {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),250);
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(),250);
        }
    };          
    vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
    vertical.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    add(vertical);      
}

protected boolean onSavePrompt()
{       
    return true;
}

public boolean onMenu(int instance) 
{
    return true;
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
    if(field==click)
    {
        browserField=new BrowserField();        
        vertical.add(browserField);
        browserField.requestContent(url);
    }
}   
}
```

I Get like this below Image;

[image: Google News]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `VerticalFieldManager` to your `MainScreen` and add your `BrowserField` to your `VerticalFieldManager`. You should set style of `VerticalFieldManager` with `VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR` and clear the syle of your `MainScreen`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! The browserField is added to a VFM, and I changed the Style to VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR but nothing has changed. How do I clear the style of the MainScreen? I am really new to BlackBerry.

Comment: My application is running like you described. My schema is like this: MainScreen --> VFM1 --> VFM2

on VFM1 i set style USE_ALL_WIDTH | USE_ALL_HEIGHT
on VFM2 i set style VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_HCENTER

VFM1 contains one BitmapField that holds background image, and VFM2 is the main panel that holds remaining UI items and on VMF2 i set padding top some space, and only VMF2 scrolls, i hope this helps